# Jquery autocomplete ... call a function after completing ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

In official documentation page i find below code http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```
 $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
source: "search.json",
minLength: 2,
select: function( event, ui ) {
log( ui.item ?
"Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
"Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
}
});
```

What i need is after ajax call is made to search.json , I need to store the returned json data from remote in a variable and then call a function.How to do it ? thanks.

Comment: Please read the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: Its returning object...when i cosole.log(ui) ..its empty..i need the whole json in a variable

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the autocomplete with the response callback specified:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  response: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Bind an event listener to the autocompleteresponse event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "autocompleteresponse", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Source: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Comment: can u tell wher to add event listenr ?

Comment: Its returning object...when i cosole.log(ui) ..its empty..i need the whole json in a variable

Comment: you can add the event listener in the $(window).load(function(){..});